INDIRECT does not work with table but it does with Named ranges
INDIRECT returns a reference giving as input a string either an explicit range or a named range but does not allow the same with tables.

explicit ranges:  =INDIRECT("A2:B4")
named ranges:   =INDIRECT("DATA")

But it doesn't work for tables:

 =INDIRECT("Table1")
Output:


What's the question? How to select cells from another table? Have you tried specifying cells after the table name? Maybe there is no implied "all cells" of this table.

The INDIRECT object is a reference to elements, and can be used in functions. For example, using it to add up all the elements, with named ranges and fixed ranges I can modify the data and obtain the updated data, but it doesn't work with tables.

As of now TABLE references are not supported by INDIRECT() or IMPORTRANGE()

As this is a new feature, some functions are not yet integrated to it. However, you may still use some functions by referencing the sheet's name (where the table is placed) instead.

I did try =INDIRECT("A2:B4") outside the table (in my test case, E1), and it returned the values from A2:B4. I also tried to implement the function in Sheet2 with: =INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2:B4") on A1 and it worked. You just need to reference the sheet itself and not the table as this is still a new feature.

The indirect() function doesn't currently (September 2024) support any sort of structured table references. Google is aware of the issue but there is no published timeline for a solution.
